# autosuggestion is not working using canjs

Tags: javascript, canjs

I am trying to to create auto suggest element manually. I am using canjs for this prupose.

Following code I have tried so far:

```
list.filter( function( item, index, list ) {
   if(item.includes(searchText) && searchText != ''){
     //css hide and show classes for match
   }
   else{
      // css show for unmatched results
   }
})
```

In above code I am facing two problems:

1. includes does not work in all browsers. For that I have tried match,
   contains and sub-string but they could not help me.
2. includes working in chrome but when I entered  the string whose 
   substring  is not contained by the last element of list it will not
   work because filter will keep searching from all the elements.

Is there any mistake I am doing?

I want to it to run in all the browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.includes()` with one argument is equivalent to applying `!!~` operators to `String.prototype.indexOf()`, and the latter one works in all browsers.  So your test line can be this:

`if(!!~item.indexOf(searchText) && searchText !== '’){`